# cmake Installing many libraries so that find_package can access them

Tags: installation, cmake, export

I've got a source tree with many src directories (lots of use of add_subdirectory), and
I would like to install all of them and be able to use find_package to include them into another project.
After getting mightly confused with install(EXPORT.... , .cmake and config.cmake files,
please could someone tell me the right way of approaching this.

Thanks

Comment: "After getting mightly confused with ..." - What **exactly** confuses you? Have you tried to follow any tutorial? E.g. the [official one](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html).

Comment: Following such tutorials, I've managed to install/export 1 of my libraries. I've got 20 or so src directories each creating a (little) library each with it's own header directory. What's the best way to install/export these without having to call find_package 20 times?

Comment: "without having to call find_package 20 times?" - You may `install(TARGETS ... EXPORT)` into the same export set as many libraries as you want. And you may have a single config file for as many export files as you want. Not sure what is a problem.

Comment: I didn't know you could add more things to the "export set". I had tried it , but probably got the order wrong, Seems to be working now thanks..